# Review privilege abuse

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-abuse

I have been trying to find the "correct" amount of editing to do when I see a posted question or answer with obvious issues.  Fore front in my mind is that I want to make it clearer for the next person who comes across the question.  I have had a few comments passed, which I thought might be rejected for being too minor, in terms of the number of characters changed, but were significant in relation to them being key words that people would search for...anyhow digressing slightly from my question.

In all cases I reviewed the reason for the Reject votes, even on the question that got Approved, for my own learning.

What I noticed was a huge discrepancy between reviewer stats, where some were rejecting as few 10% while others were rejecting as high as 80%. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5545482) where a user has performed over 11000 reviews.

I don't want to try to do the maths, regarding the likelihood of getting a good edit rejected by people who are keen to reject, versus the chance of getting a bad edit past people who are keen to accept.  But it is obvious that there are large discrepancies amongst some reviewers.

To take the point further, I was trying to find out information about whether reviewers accept/reject rates were monitored when I found a screen dump of the same reviewer on [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179362/reviewer-stats-in-suggested-edits-should-show-improver) from May last year.  This time the maths is easy, in the past 15 Months this reviewer has only approved 68 edits, and rejected 8134 for a resulting approval rate of just 0.83%.

Noting in the same post there is a user with a greater than 95% approval rate.

This is extremely inconsistent, and whether the discrepancy is due to personal strictness / leniency in the interpretation of the guidelines, or whether it is wilful abuse, it leads to disillusionment with the system.

Q1. Is there OR can there be some sort of monitoring of the accept/reject rate of individual reviewers over a period of time, and if their rate significantly differs from the community rate of accept/reject, then some action is taken.

Q2. *If* action is taken because someone is a serial approver or rejector, then should their punishment be removal of their privilege OR lowering of their review limit, so that they are encouraged to provide more "detailed" analysis of the review.

ADDENDUM:

Ok, I can see from initial feedback, that some reviewers only perform easy reviews that can be judged very quickly as bad (or maybe good), and the more complex reviews are skipped and left for someone with more experience in the specific field.

But this still leaves the question valid, but perhaps a little more refined.  In the 2 examples I mention above both reviews were "line ball", either 2/3 or 3/2. Which means the edit was perhaps a little more involved than just straight forward, and some judgement was used in these 2 cases.  Certainly my edit is very simple, in terms of the number of characters changed, but without understanding of java strings function in question, you could easily gloss over and see it is unimportant. Note: I considered adding it as a comment first, but thought the cleaner approach to an old question would be to make the minor edit.

If you reject 99% of edits AND 99% of the edits you vote on are rejected, then you are in line with the community.  However if you reject 99% of edits, but only 50% or 60% end in rejection, then you are seriously out of line with the community, as your 1 reject vote can either be the decider, or can be persuasive to reviewers who are not sure, but follower your lead.

So to refine my question to:

Q1. Is there OR can there be some sort of monitoring of the accept/reject rate of individual reviewers over a period of time, and if their rate significantly differs from **other reviewers rates of acceptance/rejection of the same item**, then some action is taken.

This is currently not discernible from the displayed stats, other than by trolling through your reviews and noticing patterns, like I did. And hey this pattern may be 1 anomaly in someone's otherwise standout set of reviews and not an indication of abuse at all.

But if I can sum up my point as follows. There are many other forms of checks on SO, including the use of reviews to ensure new users are using the site in line with the community guidelines. But are there checks on reviews to ensure that new users get consistent and correct feedback from these reviews.

Comment: For me, it's easier to spot a bad edit than a good one. So I just reject all the bad ones, and skip everything else that I can't judge in 10 seconds. Stuff like tag wiki plagiarism is usually obvious and I will serially reject all of them - each and every single one without hesitation.

Comment: @Mysticial in both the instances I show above, I don't believe the edit was trivial / obvious. In both cases the vote came down to 2 votes one way and 3 votes the other. one was rejected and the other approved (and I am not personally upset that mine was the one rejected, I thought it added value, but maybe pushed the guidelines). Maybe the measure can be obtained by comparing against the other reviewers within the same review, rather than the overall rate.

Comment: I too, usually reject the ones I am absolutely sure are bad and skip anything that I don't have proficiency to judge. I prefer skipping, so that someone who knows better than me can make an informed decision for that edit. Which is why I rarely accepted any edit in the 2K+ reviews I did. It's a matter of personal choice.

Comment: Personally, I kind of think the idea of editing is broken.  If a question is bad, just close it.  If a question is good, answer it.  Being able to fix formatting and grammar is fine, but anything else I will almost always reject, on the principle that the user who asked it knows what he wants better than the editor.  I don't think the idea of editing questions to be better actually works.

Comment: @GabeSechan FWIW I tend to clean up spelling and formatting when I believe that this will make it much easier for other readers to see why post deserves voting down and close (for the sake of completeness it also happened maybe a handful of times that upon rereading cleaned post I voted it up and left open)